# find the rows with specific pattern

Tags: pandas

I need to find entries in a data frame in which one of its columns has a specific pattern like 01-02-11-55-00115 on other words Number-number-number-number-number

```
raw_data = {'name': ['Willard Morris', 'Al Jennings', 'Omar Mullins', 'Spencer McDaniel'],
'code': ['01-02-11-55-00115','01-02-11-55-00445','test', '01-0t-11-55-00115'],
'favorite_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'yellow', &quot;green&quot;],
'grade': [88, 92, 95, 70]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)df.head()
```

retrieve the rows that have that condition , the condition will be in the 'code' column so the code has to retrieve the first and second rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with the `(\d+-){4}\d+` regex (4 times `\d+-` where `\d+` is one or more digits, followed by digits):

```
out = df[df['code'].str.fullmatch(r'(\d+-){4}\d+')]
```

If you need to match the specific "2 digits -" four times then "5 digits":

```
out = df[df['code'].str.fullmatch(r'(\d\d-){4}\d{5}')]
```

Output:

```
             name               code favorite_color  grade
0  Willard Morris  01-02-11-55-00115           blue     88
1     Al Jennings  01-02-11-55-00445           blue     92
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (*with* [`str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html)) :

```
out = df.loc[df["code"].replace("-", "", regex=True).str.isnumeric()]
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)
             name               code favorite_color  grade
0  Willard Morris  01-02-11-55-00115           blue     88
1     Al Jennings  01-02-11-55-00445           blue     92
```

Or, if you need to flag those rows, use this :

```
df["flag"] = df["code"].replace("-", "", regex=True).str.isnumeric()

print(df)
               name               code favorite_color  grade   flag
0    Willard Morris  01-02-11-55-00115           blue     88   True
1       Al Jennings  01-02-11-55-00445           blue     92   True
2      Omar Mullins               test         yellow     95  False
3  Spencer McDaniel  01-0t-11-55-00115          green     70  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter values if decimal or `-` with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and regex with `^` for start of string, decimals, `-` value and `$` for end of string:

```
df1 = df[df["code"].str.contains(r'^[0-9\-]+$')]
print (df1)
             name               code favorite_color  grade
0  Willard Morris  01-02-11-55-00115           blue     88
1     Al Jennings  01-02-11-55-00445           blue     92
```

Or for pattern `Number-number-number-number-number` use:

```
df2 = df[df["code"].str.contains(r'^\d+\-\d+\-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$')]
print (df2)
             name               code favorite_color  grade
0  Willard Morris  01-02-11-55-00115           blue     88
1     Al Jennings  01-02-11-55-00445           blue     92
```